# What's the meaning of `inet` and `inet6`?

Tags: network

When I reading a doc:

```
Logical properties settings include:
- Protocol family:
  inet 
  inet6 
  iso 
  mpls 
  bridge/ethernet-switching
```

I don't know the `inet`, `inet6`, and `iso` meaning there, I searched the google, find a `iNet`, is them equals? who can help understanding them?

Comment: What doc? You need to give more context around your question.

Comment: Based on previous questions I'd guess it's about JunOS. Juniper documented the different address families in various documents, including this one: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/interface-security-logical-property-protocol-family-understanding.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*each protocol will provide a routing table for their given address space or work with each other to provide routing between address spaces:*

inet represents [IPv4 addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) such as 8.8.8.8

inet6 represents [IPv6 addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) such as 2001:4860:4860::8888

[ISO CLNS](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/isoclns/configuration/guide/15_0s/iso_15_0s_book/configure_iso_clns.html). The International Organization for Standardization (ISO) Connectionless Network Service (CLNS) protocol is a standard for the network layer of the Open System Interconnection (OSI) model

[Multiprotocol Label Switching (MPLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprotocol_Label_Switching) is a type of data-carrying technique for high-performance telecommunications networks. MPLS directs data from one network node to the next based on short path labels rather than long network addresses

Answer (score 3):

*inet* usually refers to IPv4, *inet6* to IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

To be clearer, inet is a short for Internet. And IPvX stands for Internet Protocol version X.
So indeed inet will be regular Internet Protocol (v4) and inet6 the v6 of the Internet Protocol.